# Criar Tarefa banco de dados MySql

Tags: php, mysql, tabela-html, banco-de-dados

Preciso criar uma JOB(conhecida em sqlserver) em um banco mysql, primeiro, gostaria de saber se existe essa possibilidade, e caso exista, como seria a sintaxe?

Tenho uma Tabela que guarda uma coluna date, quero que o banco execute uma tarefa se a date for igual a data atual.

Comment: Você quer que isto aconteça quando? De tempos em tempos? Quando é inserido, atualizado?

Comment: Maniero, existe a possibilidade de eu atualizar uma tabela e em determinada hora do dia seguinte ela atualizar novamente ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fala mestre então encontrei para você, sim tem como fazer job no mysql como fala neste site: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Algo como nesse exemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `archive_blogs` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2011-07-24 03:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

        -- copy deleted posts
        INSERT INTO blog_archive (id, title, content) 
        SELECT id, title, content
        FROM blog
        WHERE deleted = 1;

        -- copy associated audit records
        INSERT INTO audit_archive (id, blog_id, changetype, changetime) 
        SELECT audit.id, audit.blog_id, audit.changetype, audit.changetime 
        FROM audit
        JOIN blog ON audit.blog_id = blog.id
        WHERE blog.deleted = 1;

        -- remove deleted blogs and audit entries
        DELETE FROM blog WHERE deleted = 1;

    END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Só adaptar a sua necessidade e boa.

Adicionando referencia completa ao event: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html